# Do not convert JToken date time string as DateTime

Tags: c#, json, parsing, datetime

Trying to parse JToken which is holding datetime as string, as string. Implicitly what it is doing is considering it as DateTime, parsing and then passing back as string.

Original value is : `"2015-11-23T00:00:00"`

When I do `arr["value"].ToString();`
I get : `"23/11/2015 00:00:00"`

What I really want is whatever was passed i.e. the original value.

Have tried using `Formatting.None`, but that brings in double quotes etc.

Is there a simple way round?

Comment: What do you mean by _What I really want is whatever was passed_ exactly? You mean the same representation as `2015-11-23T00:00:00` as a string?

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes, exactly same thing as string literal. No type conversion.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `DateParseHandling` to override JSON.NET's automatic attempts to DateTimeify anything that looks DateTimey.

```
void Main()
{
    var s = "{ \"value\" : \"2015-11-23T00:00:00\" }";

    using (var sr = new StringReader(s))
    using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr) { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None })
    {
        var j = JToken.ReadFrom(jr);
        Console.WriteLine(j["value"].ToString()); // prints '2015-11-23T00:00:00'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can describe the class with this member declared as 'string' and use it in serialization, so that it is is stored in the original representation:

```
public class MyObject 
{ 
    public string date { get; set ; }
}

string json = "{ \"date\": \"2015-11-23T00:00:00\" }";
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);

Console.WriteLine(myObj.date);
```

Comment: It is actually JArray, which is key value pair. And JToken that needs to be parsed to string, so middleware can handle it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem:

```java
public static string DateToStringExact(dynamic date)
{
     string dateString = date.ToString(Formatting.None);  // return "2021-01-01T00:00:00"

     // To return only 2021-01-01T00:00:00 (without ""):
     string res = dateString.Substring(1, dateString.Length-2); 
     //or
     string res = dateString.Replace("\"", "");
     return res;
}
```

You can call this function by:

```java
string x = DateToStringExact(arr["value"])
```

Answer (score -3):

First `SerializeObject` and then `DeserializeObject` to get the safe value of the date field.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
```