# Json.NET ToObject Date Serialization Format

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm trying to set a custom date format when using Newtonsoft.Json ToObject to convert from JSON to my custom Object but trying different ways I can't get it to alter the date format at all.

```
public class CustomObject
        {
            public string DateRecordedString { get; set; }
        }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonResult = "[{\"daterecordedstring\":\"2016-11-21T08:24:42\"}]";
            JToken jtokenResult = JToken.Parse(jsonResult);

            var objectResult1 = jtokenResult.ToObject<CustomObject[]>();
            Console.WriteLine(objectResult1.First().DateRecordedString); // -> 11/21/2016 08:24:42

            var objectResult2 = jtokenResult.ToObject<CustomObject[]>(new JsonSerializer { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None });
            Console.WriteLine(objectResult2.First().DateRecordedString); // -> 11/21/2016 08:24:42

            var objectResult3 = jtokenResult.ToObject<CustomObject[]>(new JsonSerializer { DateFormatString = "yyyy-M-d" });
            Console.WriteLine(objectResult3.First().DateRecordedString); // -> 11/21/2016 08:24:42

        }
```

How can I get ToObject to return a date in the format I want (or leave it unchanged)?

Comment: Have you read this http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm?

Comment: Yes thanks, but it hasn't helped - for whatever reason my code above is always producing m/d/y type format.

Comment: What "culture" is your environment in?

Comment: New Zealand and m/d/y isn't my date format

Comment: Doing some reading i found that JToken parse might be your culprit.  see http://stackoverflow.com/q/33874334/1841212
Seems like the conversion happens earlier than you are expecting

Comment: You're right it was doing the conversion earlier than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `JToken.Parse` is doing some type conversion before you do.

As answered in [Do not convert JToken date time string as DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874334/do-not-convert-jtoken-date-time-string-as-datetime)

```
void Main()
{
     string jsonResult = "[{\"daterecordedstring\":\"2016-11-21T08:24:42\"}]";

    using (var sr = new StringReader(jsonResult))
    using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr) { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None })
    {
        var j = JToken.ReadFrom(jr);
        Console.WriteLine(j["value"].ToString()); // prints '2016-11-21T08:24:42'
    }
}
```

full kudos to user5090812

Answer (score 1):

JToken's **ToObject** doesn't respect **DateParseHandling=DateParseHandling.None**

The code as below:
item=>**JToken** type

```
Dictionary<string, string> data = item.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(new JsonSerializer { DateParseHandling=DateParseHandling.None});
```

No work, it still converts to MM/dd/yyyy.

In my case, I get JArray from deserialized string, remember each item in JArray is JToken.

To make it work, add none format instruction before it generates JToken.

So, add **DateParseHandling=DateParseHandling.None** on deserialize level before it generate JArray.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, new JsonSerializerSettings {  DateParseHandling=DateParseHandling.None}) as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray;
```

Now, if you loop through this JArray for each JToken and use JToken.ToObject, you will get none formatted datetime.